# Flattening a tree using MR, how can I recursively join in PIG/HIVE/MR?

Tags: hive, apache-pig, flatten, hierarchical

I wish to flatten a data hierarchy using Pig/Hive/MR. 
Below is the sample input which represents a tree structure:

```
Child|Parent
B|A
D|B
E|B
C|A
```

Required output which represents the path to root node

```
B,A
D,B,A
E,B,A
C,A
```

By doing a recursive left self join I wanted to traverse up the tree. Is this 
doable using any of these tools?

Comment: Did you find an answer to that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle recursive hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519561/how-to-handle-recursive-hierarchy)